# No value given for one or more required parameters in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm having trouble when working with database in C#.
The problem is **No value given for one or more required parameters** whenever I click any buttons INSERT, DELETE, SEARCH,...
I check the field name and everything looks good. I have no idea what's wrong.
I include part of my source code below. Hopefully someone could guide me through this. Thank you!

```
namespace AccessDataForm
{
    public partial class TourForm : Form
    {
        public TourForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void tourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void viewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disp_data();
        }

        public void disp_data()
        {
            string strSql = "Select * from Tour";
            sql_exec(strSql);
        }

        private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tourIDTbx.Text))
            {
                messageLbl2.Visible = true;
                messageLbl2.Text = "Tour ID will be assigned by the Access DBMS";
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tripLengthTbx.Text) ||
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationTbx.Text) ||
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(detailTbx.Text) ||
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(priceTbx.Text))
                {
                    messageLbl2.Text = "Warning:  Some fields are missing data";
                }
                else
                {
                    string strSql = "Insert INTO Tour ([TripLengthInDays], [Destination], [Detail], [PricePerPerson]) VALUES (";
                    strSql += "'" + tripLengthTbx.Text + "', '" + destinationTbx.Text;
                    strSql += "', '" + detailTbx.Text + "', '" + priceTbx.Text + "');";
                    sql_exec(strSql);
                    clearTextBox();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record inserted!!");
                    messageLbl2.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void deleteBtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tourID_check();
        }

        private void deleteBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageLbl2.Visible = false;
            messageLbl2.Text = "";
        }

        private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strSql = "DELETE FROM Tour WHERE [Tour ID] = ";
            strSql += tourIDTbx.Text;
            sql_exec(strSql);
            messageLbl2.Text = "";
            //MessageBox.Show("Record deleted!");
        }

        private void searchBtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tourID_check();
        }

        private void searchBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageLbl2.Visible = false;
            messageLbl2.Text = "";
        }

        private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strSql = "Select * from Tour where [Tour ID] = ";
            strSql += tourIDTbx.Text;
            sql_exec(strSql);
            messageLbl2.Text = "";
        }

        private void editBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strSql = "UPDATE Tour SET ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tripLengthTbx.Text))
                strSql += "[TripLengthInDays] = '" + tripLengthTbx.Text + "', ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationTbx.Text))
                strSql += "[Destination] = '" + destinationTbx.Text + "', ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(detailTbx.Text))
                strSql += "[Detail] = '" + detailTbx.Text + "', ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(priceTbx.Text))
                strSql += "[PricePerPerson] = '" + priceTbx.Text + "' ";
            strSql += "WHERE[Tour ID] = ";
            strSql += tourIDTbx.Text;
            sql_exec(strSql);
            clearTextBox();
            //MessageBox.Show("Record edited!!");
        }

        private void editBtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageLbl2.Visible = true;
            messageLbl2.Text = "Please enter all fields for the operation";
        }

        private void editBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageLbl2.Visible = false;
            messageLbl2.Text = "";
        }

        public void clearTextBox()
        {
            tourIDTbx.Text = "";
            tripLengthTbx.Text = "";
            destinationTbx.Text = "";
            detailTbx.Text = "";
            priceTbx.Text = "";
        }

        public void tourID_check()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tourIDTbx.Text))
            {
                messageLbl2.Visible = true;
                messageLbl2.Text = "Please enter Tour's ID for the operation";
            }
            else
                messageLbl2.Text = "";
        }

        public void sql_exec(string strSql)
        {
            //using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=\Users\selin2\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AccessDataForm\ExploringTravelAgent.accdb"))
            using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=ExploringTravelAgent.accdb"))

            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con1);
                    con1.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable agent = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(agent);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = agent;
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con1.Close();
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how my Table looks like:
[SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75imj.png)

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. Don't post all the code you have.

Comment: Is this code from 20 years ago?? Please use parameterised queries (and stored procedures if possible), or a tool like Entity Framework. Don't build SQL up through string concatenation - because a) it makes errors much more likely and hard to debug, and b) you are wide open to SQL injection. A malicious user could completely corrupt or destroy your data by entering SQL into your UI. (Obligatory and classic XKCD: https://xkcd.com/327/)